# Cannot read properly "split"

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code in javascript:

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0; 

while (allTextLines.length) {
    var line = allTextLines.shift().split('"');
    var temp = line[1].split('');

    if (i == 0) {
        alert(temp);
        i++;
    }

    var x = (temp[0] + temp[1]+ temp[2] + temp[3] + "-" + temp[4] + temp[5] + temp[6]);
    var y = line[3]; 
    var z = line[5]; 
    var g = line[7]; 

    lines[j] = (x + ", " + z + ", " + g);
    j++;
}
```

And it's happening something really weird. When `i==0`, it alerts `temp` and its split. After that I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

If I remove the `if`, I will have this error right on the start. But if I do something like this:

```
var line = allTextLines.shift().split('"');
var temp = line[1].split('');
alert(temp);
var x = (temp[0] + temp[1]+ temp[2] + temp[3] + "-" + temp[4] + temp[5] + temp[6]);
```

It has no problem splitting (also the alert shows that it has been correctly split). The only problem is that I will have to click "ok" 5600 times. I don't understand what the hell is going on and why I am having this error.

I'm splitting a CSV file with lines like this:

```
35105,201401,503781827,"8400258","Faro","Lagoa (Algarve)","Portugal"
```

and I'm trying to add an '-' in here: "8400258", so it becomes "8400-258"

[image]

Comment: Please provide an executable snippet with an example value for `allTextLines`

Comment: 35105,201401,503781827,"8400258","Faro","Lagoa (Algarve)","Portugal"

like this?

Comment: in the question would be better.

Comment: Just [edit] the code into the question. And please check that it demonstrates the issue... My guess would be that you're somehow asynchronously filling the array? Please add the code that reads in the CSV file.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error (check the linenumber) - in the `line` computation or the `temp` one?

Comment: var temp = line[1].split(''); after line[1]

Comment: Your first two example values don't have quotes, so `line[1]` should't be defined (because there are no quotes to split on).

Comment: Well if `line[1]` is `undefined` then you've read a line in your file that does not contain a quote… Does your file contain such?

Comment: but why if I put an alert(temp); right after var temp = line[1].split('');, it has no problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var line = allTextLines.shift().split('"');
var temp = line[1].split('');
```

Won't that fail when allTextLines only has one element in it, since the array is zero-based? I think you'd need to change the line[x] param to 0:

```
var temp = line[0].split('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest a different approach?

```
var line = allTextLines.shift().split(',');
var x = line[3].replace(/^"(\d{4})(\d{3})"$/, "$1-$2");
var y = line[4];
var z = line[5];
var g = line[6];
```

If you can trust that the format of the data is always the same, it's much less complex to do a pattern based replace than splitting a string like an array and re-assembling it.